# Avoid scrollbars when resizing flexbox in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, flexbox

Consider the below trio of nested divs. There's a flexbox containing one child with `flex: 1`, that in turn contains one child with `height: 100%`.

```css
body, html {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}

.container {
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: red;
}

.body {
  background-color: blue;
  flex: 1;
}

.inner {
  background-color: yellow;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="inner">
      
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

If you decrease the size of the window in Chrome, a vertical scrollbar will appear. This does not happend in Firefox. It seems like Chrome does not recalculate what 100% height means when the element containing it is resized.

Is this a bug in Chrome? Can this be fixed somehow, under the restriction that I can't change the markup and I have to use the flexbox?

Answer (score 1):

It does seem to be a Chrome bug, as opening the Dev-Tools and disabling/re-enabling `flex: 1` solves it. I found that adding `overflow: hidden` to your `.body` solves the issue (at least in my JSFiddle). I hope this helps your case.

https://jsfiddle.net/a89ksz4d/

Comment: Yeah, that toggling the style fixes it sure makes it sound like a bug. Thanks! `overflow: hidden` isn't an option for me unfortunately, since it doesnt work if the flexbox has more than one child, or if things inside inner needs to resize based on the size. But it should fix the problem for many other cases.

Comment: @Anders ah I see, too bad. Would adding `height: 100%` instead of `overflow: hidden` to your `.body` be a better solution? It seems to be the same, see: https://jsfiddle.net/a89ksz4d/2/

BTW with two elements it becomes obvious, that Chrome just doesn't scale the children when making the parent smaller (it does when making the parent bigger, though). So I'm pretty sure it's in fact a Chrome bug